# Hide ImageView on horizontal

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have a **ImageView** in the program, which limits the viewing area.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/log_t"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

How to make it invisible at the screen horizontal orientation and back again visible in the vertical?

Can I do it in one XML layout? Or I must to do a separate layout for the horizontal view and vertical view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the container activity you can add:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) (or GONE instead of invisible)
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
}
```

Comment: After **protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** ?

Comment: after or before, there is no difference, is an indepent function